# python subprocess for convert command does anything

Tags: python, django, subprocess, imagemagick-convert

I have a function to convert a pdf file to a thumbnail after upload.

```
def book_post_save(sender, instance=False, **kwargs):

     pdf = Post.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)
     command = "convert -quality 95 -thumbnail 100 %s%s[0] %s%s" % (
             settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
             pdf.file,
             settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
             pdf.file
         )
     proc = subprocess.Popen(
             command,
             shell=True,
             stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
             stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
             stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
         )
     stdout_value = proc.communicate()[0]

post_save.connect(book_post_save, sender=Post)
```

But the subprocess command doesn't return anything. I tried to type it in a terminal but I got a **subprocess-error-returned-non-zero-exit-status-1**.
I got no thumbnail generated.

Comment: Have you looked at stderr? It is very likely that a useful error message is contained within.

Comment: No @Shadow , how can I look for it?

Comment: `proc.communicate()` returns a tuple - `(stdout, stderr)`. Your code, by having `[0]` after `communicate()`, is throwing away stderr. I would suggest doing something like `stdout_value, stderr_value = proc.communicate()` instead which will allow you to look at the contents of stderr.

Comment: @Shadow Yeah adding stderr_value, I finally see error and correct it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason you're struggling here is that you're throwing away your error message.

The [communicate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) method returns a tuple with two elements, `stdin` and `stdout`. The code above (namely `proc.communicate()[0]`) is taking the first element (stdin) but ignoring stderr.

So I would suggest modifying your code to do the following;

```
stdout_value, stderr_value = proc.communicate()
```

Once you've done this, if the process fails, you can print `stderr_value` and work out why the process failed.

Comment: Yeah it's already done. I replied in your comment. Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I added my comment as an answer. Thanks for accepting it :)